# C++ macro to log every line of code

Tags: c++, c, logging, macros

During one of my recent discussions with my manager, he mentioned that one of his former clients used a C++ macro to log info about every line of code. All they had to do was enable an environment variable before starting the run. (Of course the environment variable was enabled in the test-bed alone.

The log mentioned the variables used and their corresponding values too. 
For example, for the line:

```
a = a + b;
```

The log would say something like:

```
"a = a + b; (a = 5 + 3)"
```

Personally, I was not sure if this was possible, but he was very sure of this having existed, though he did not remember the specifics of the code.

So, here is the (obvious) question: Is this possible? Can you provide the code for this one?

Comment: In your question, I am wrapping double quotes for the log message (to show that it's a log message). Hope it's ok.

Comment: There's no such thing as a C++ macro, and this certainly isn't possible with vanilla C Preprocessor macros. Some other tool must be generating the value strings.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to log bare lines like "a = a + b", but using a macro in the line like "LOG(a = a + b)" is possible, and assert macro's are already doing it.

Comment: what possible value could this provide? Surely it's better to run inside a debugger to obtain this information...

Comment: I think it is not that difficult to write a custom preprocessor that places each line of the code between a LOG() macro

Answer (score 19):

I don't know if every line/variable can be expanded like that, but function calls can be logged. I have logged all function calls using the `-finstrument-functions` option of gcc. It will call:

```
  void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *this_fn, void *call_site);
```

and

```
   void __cyg_profile_func_exit  (void *this_fn, void *call_site);
```

for function enter and exit.

[The docs explain how to use it.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options) I don't know if other compilers offer something similar.

Comment: MSVC++ has `/Gh` and `/GH` for `_penter()` and `_pexit()` functions, which get called at the beginning and end of each function, respectively: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may check how [BOOST_CHECKA from Boost.Test is implemented](https://github.com/ryppl/boost-svn/blob/ddcc4ecc54e98dc5261e4698a541d8f4ba4dc77b/boost/test/test_tools.hpp). Internally it uses expression templates.

For test:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN

#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/test_tools.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test1)
{
    int a=0;
    int b=1;
    int c=2;
    BOOST_CHECKA( a+b == c );
}
```

Output is:

```
Running 1 test case...
main.cpp(11): error: in "test1": check a+b == c failed [0+1!=2]

*** 1 failure detected in test suite "Master Test Suite"
```

Note values in square brackets: **[0+1!=2]**

It has some limitations.

For test:

```
BOOST_CHECKA( (a+b) == c );
```

output is:

```
check (a+b) == c failed [1!=2]
```